# Installing Ubuntu on Lenovo IdeaPad U530 with windows 8.1 preinstalled

Tags: installation, lenovo

There has been a lot of discussion on installing Ubuntu on machines with preinstalled windows 8.1. I noticed that a great amount of work is required. Before I go through with this, I was wondering if anyone installed Ubuntu successfully on exactly the model that I have which is Lenovo IdeaPad U530 and if there are specific tips/problems with the installation.

Comment: that is how I installed it successfully https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Any-luck-setting-up-a-Windows-8-Linux-dual-boot-system-on-U530/td-p/1404835

Answer (score 0):

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 specifically gnome flavor in my lenovo u530. I am facing an issue with wifi. The problem is specific to the intel 7260 wifi used in this particular ultrabook.

I am still searching for a solution to fix the wifi problem. Wifi disconnects every two minutes and hardly works